# How to configure Microsoft Healthbot?

Tags: azure, react-native, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm working on a project to integrate a healthcare assistant bot on a mobile application with React Native

I saw that there was a bot from Microsoft for health and therefore adapted for my project, so I would like to use it

So I created an account on Azure and created my bot, however I can't and don't really understand how to configure it to use it and integrate it into my project.

On the Microsoft documentation I see that we have to configure the DirectLine to use a Microsoft bot but I can't activate this on mine, I don't have the option, moreover it's considered as a Saas and not as a bot application on azure, so I don't have the same options and I don't really understand exactly why (I tried with the cli without success, so I think we can't configure DirectLine on a HealthBot)

Then I found this https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/tree/live_agent_handoff

The README.md indicates that we must deploy the bot, which I did, I also set the variables to add. But then I don't know exactly what to do to integrate that into my application. I also wonder how to take into account the creation of scenarios on azure.

If someone could enlighten me on how I should proceed to integrate this, I would be grateful. I also saw that there was a module (react-gifted-chat) for creating chat bot, but in the tutorials I meet, everyone uses the DirectLine, so I wonder if it's possible or do I have to go through a Web View?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a doc, titled “Embed a health bot instance in your application”, that should answer your questions. You can find the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/integrations/embed).

It includes:

- GitHub samples
- Code examples
- Steps for securing communication
- Information on how to setup Direct Line
- A link and steps for setting up WebChat as an iframe or web page element (in a div, for example)

Hope of help!